# How do I properly clean up Inactive or Orphan Interop EXCEL process?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I want clean Inactive/Ideal excel processes which have 0 CPU usages. 
Mean While generating excel report, If we close the browser, excel remains open.
I want to find such processes and close it.

How to achieve it using C#?

Comment: Just don't use Excel through interop. Use a library like EPPlus to create an Excel file without having Excel installed. As for your specific problem, it's impossible to help without the code. If you used `using` to dispose of objects properly, you wouldn't have an issue

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The application is already hosted on Production Server, in gives issues once in month when multiple Inactive excel processes remains opened, And stops generating new excel reports. Near about after 10 excel inactive processes, report generations stops. That is the reason I need to find such inactive processes and close them.

Comment: I can rewrite the code using EPPlus or OpenXML. But for now need to overcome with the above issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)